# Unload a dll using ctypes (or other) in python

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I'm struggling to unload a previously loaded fortran compiled dll inside a python loop.
One important info : the dll is mine. I’m compiling the dll myself in VS with IFX compiler.

Here is the issue :
I need to make a bunch of simulations changing some parameters here and there. All runs use the same external dll.

Here is an example of my way do do it from now

```py
    import ctypes as ct

    param = # list of parameter value I'd like to study
    results = []

    for val in param:
        # the dll is loaded
        dll = ct.CDLL(my_dll_path)
        #function that plays with the dll
        results.append(dll.compute_What_I_Want(val))
    
        #I want to unload the dll to open a new instance in the next loop
        handle = dll._handle
        del dll
        ct.windll.kernel32.FreeLibrary.argtypes = [wintypes.HMODULE]
        ct.windll.kernel32.FreeLibrary(handle)
```

the issue is that the second loop fails because my dll says that internal variables are already allocated: Fortran severe error :

```
forrtl: severe (151): allocatable array is already allocated.
```

Using multiprocessing doesn’t solve the issue because : 1 core (1 thread) -> 1dll, but once the simulation is done on a specific thread, I still cannot open a new instance of the dll within the same thread because the dll returns the same Error (see above).

I’ve tried to implement in a new dll function inside fortran with the “STOP” command. But this just kills the python process as well. So I guess the dll needs to be closed inside python and not by fortran itself.

I’m currently compiling the dll in VS using IFX compiler, is there some option I should add to the compiler in order to enable the dll to be closed nicely using ctypes FreeLibrary function ?
Or is there a way to just kill the dll inside python by its PID or ID for the core being used ?

I've made so many tries, looking at so many threads related to this topics without getting any solution...

NB : a workaround could be to deallocate all the variables inside the fortran code when the first dll function is called (it’s a classic init_solver function), but the drawback is that it would require an enormous work and impacts the architecture of the global fortran code -> Not a good option at this stage. When the dll doesn’t exist in the first place, things work perfectly.

thanks in advance for any help
(env. : windows, python 3.9)

Comment: If freeing the library doesn't clear the state sufficiently, you could be running the load-DLL-compute-result thing in a `multiprocessing` subprocess.

Comment: thanks, this goes ok for one set of simulations with no feed back from previous. What if I want to tune the next parameter depending on the results from the previous runs (or from several runs). I still need to find a way to remove this dll from the environment.

Comment: How to properly unload it probably also depends on the DLL itself.

Comment: Show a [mcve]. If multiprocessing doesn’t work , show *that* [mcve]

Comment: I'm trying to understand: you want to unload the *.dll* while keeping some of its internal variables? That doesn't make sense. Looking at the code, the obvious question pops up: **why instantiating *CDLL* inside the loop**? Please also show the traceback as instructed in [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (already mentioned in comments). You're unloading the library but never check if it actually succeeded.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn’t clear from the beginning, I tried to rephrase the question. I'd like to load a dll, make some computation, release it and open a new instance of it to make other computation. The dll load a file that allocates the internal variable so by releasing it I can created a new instance from scratch, otherwise, I'd need to create a new function inside the dll that deallocate all internal variables.

Comment: Seems like's a serious flaw in the *.dll*, or or it was designed to only call the simulation once (which is the same thing), and you're looking for workarounds. Why not fixing the problem like creating a cleanup function (which really cleans stuff up, not only the tings required for this scenario to work)? Again, you don't check unloading result.

Comment: Indeed, the solution might be within the dll. But I tried to use ISO_C_BINDING and C_interface_module in fortran for each function with same results. I've checked if the dll was closed, but no....even del dll remove the variable but the process seems to be still openned somewhere (psutil.Process(proc.info['pid'] withtin python and looping through process.memory_maps()) gives me an ID for the dll...

Comment: The *DLL* should de-allocate things and FreeLibrary shouldn't be relied on, but if you insist on it, call FreeLibrary until it returns True (success).  That's not particularly safe either.  If there are multiple references to the DLL that you don't know about, forcing an unload could later crash Python.